# How to share variables between ejs and page script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

In my page, I have a select box populated via `ejs`:

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="clienti" style="height: 150px" required>
  <% for(var i=0; i<clienti.length; i++) {%>
    <option ><%= clienti[i]["Cliente"] %></option>
  <% } %>
</select>
```

I want to display in a div some info with this code `<%= codiceLisa[x]["Codice_Lisa"] %>` the `x` variable needs to be the index of the selected item in the `<select>` tag.

I have already tried this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("clienti").selectedIndex;
```

but seems like ejs can't see the `x` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `selected` for `option` to use `selectedIndex` of this element.
Look like :

```
<option value="example value" selected="">Something</option>
```